# how upload file from folder in php then deleted it after uploaded

Tags: php, sql-server, file, xampp, unlink

I am trying to upload a file from one folder on my Pc to another folder on the XAMPP server. Then after uploaded the file must be deleted from the source.

I have written this code which uploads the file to the folder on the XAMPP server but does not remove it from the source and it shows the error "Unlink resource temporarily unavailable".
my code is :

```
 <?php
 if (isset($_POST['save'])) { 
      // destination of the file on the server
    $destination = 'uploads/' . $filename;
    $file = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];
    $size = $_FILES['myfile']['size'];
  
$filepath = 'uploads/'.$filename  ;
//-------------------------------
        elseif (file_exists($filepath))  {

 echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo ' alert(" Failed, Sanad already exist")'; 
 
echo '</script>';

} else {
            if (move_uploaded_file($file, $destination)) {
        
$filename = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
    //$filename = $_POST['myfile'];
     //$file_Path = 'uploads.$filename;
         $file_Path = 'D:/pic/'.$filename;
    echo $file_Path ;
    // check if the file exist
    if(file_exists($file_Path))
    {  unset($filename);
        unlink($file_Path);
        echo 'File Deleted';
    }else{
        echo 'File Not Exist';
    }       
}
            
}
   
}
    ?>
    


<html>
  <head>

    </head>
<body >
<form action="tt.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class= "form" >

   <h3>Upload File</h3>
          <input type="file" name="myfile" > <br>
 
   <button type="submit" class ="add "name="save" value="save" class = "button"> save</button>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you trying to delete files on the client computer after the upload has finished? Imagine the security nightmares if web sites had sufficient access to do that.

Comment: @yes, as soon as he or she uploaded the file then must be the file cut from the folder to another one on the server. Any idea how can do it please